# How to form a Pandas DataFrame from multiple multi dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a multi dimensional array `x_train_pad.shape =  (900, 3)` , and `x2_train_pad.shape =  (900, 7)` , and `x_train_data.shape =  (900, 5)`.
Now the DataFrame to be created should of shape  `outDF.shape = (900, ( 3+7+5) ) which is 900,15`.

Where x_train_data is a DataFrame , I want to retain the column names as is.
x_train_pad, and x2_train_pad are Numpy Array, and the resulting DataFrame may have names like x_1,x_2,X_3 ...X2_1,X2_2...X2_7 .

Comment: You can use `np.concatenate` to create a (900,15) array, and a `columns` parameter to set the column names.

Comment: Got Something working 
seqDf=pd.DataFrame(x_train_pad)#.shape
#seqDf
seqDf2 = pd.DataFrame(x_train_pad) #.shape
result = pd.concat([seqDf, seqDf2], axis=1, sort=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr1 = np.random.rand(10,3)
arr2 = np.random.rand(10,5)
arr3 = np.random.rand(10,7)

c_array = np.c_[arr1,arr2,arr3]
cols = [f"x{j+1}_{i+1}" for j, arr in enumerate([arr1[0],arr2[0],arr3[0]]) 
                    for i,_ in enumerate(arr) ]
df = pd.DataFrame(c_array, columns=cols)
display(df)
```